# HTML saving data between forms

Tags: javascript, html, forms, hta

I am developing an HTA application. I want to store (temporarily) form data between multiple pages using JavaScript. I normally would setup a PHP Webserver but the company policies do not permit web servers on the network.

So I need to pass data with JScript or some other means.

It needs to work with IE6+ on XP and 7.

I looked into HTML5 storage and it won't work in IE6, IE7.

Thank you for the info but is there any other way to pass data between two pages without a webserver?

Comment: Does this data contain sensitive information?

Comment: HTA? This still exists? I guess you are limited to IE also?

Comment: No the data contains no sensitive information. It's never submitted. Just using it to help our End Users print out a webpage that has their password and expiration date on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ActiveXObject named `FileSystemObject`. `fso` works at least with IE>=5. Below code shows basic usage of `fso`.

ActiveXObject definition:

```
var fso=new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
```

Reading file:

```
var iStream=fso.OpenTextFile('filePath',1,false);
iStream.ReadAll();
/* or looped iStream.ReadLine() */
iStream.Close();
```

Writing file:

```
var oStream=fso.OpenTextFile('filePath',2,true);
oStream.WriteLine(/*your_data*/);// This usually is looped according to your data
oStream.Close();
```

Delete file:

```
fso.DeleteFile('filePath'[,read-only]);
```

The optional `read-only` argument lets you to delete read-only files too (if `true`), by default this argument is `false`.

[FileSystemObject in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6kxy1a51%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

BTW, HTA supports HTML5 with IE9 (as well as IE9 itself), when including `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=9">` in the document.

Comment: the filePath, is this on the server or on the client? Also is there a JavaScript equivalent?

Comment: Both paths can be used depending where you want to save/read your file. The code is JavaScript, you can use `Scripting.FileSystemObject` just like you've used `WScript.Network` in your previous questions.

Comment: Thank you for all your help. I've seen your coding style fso and ostream usually used with VBScript. Thats why I was confused.

Answer (score 6):

hi why dont you store your  values in html5 storage objects such as sessionStorage/localStorage, visit  [Html5 Storage Doc](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)  to get more details. using this you can store intermediate values temporaryly/permanently locally and then access your values 
for storing values for a session

```
sessionStorage.getItem('label')
sessionStorage.setItem('value', 'label')
```

or store values permanently using

```
localStorage.getItem('label')
localStorage.setItem('value', 'label')
```

So you can store (temporarily) form data between multiple pages using html5 storage objects

Comment: does HTA support HTML5? This sounds like a good idea. I'll start looking into it. Just so you know, there is no server. The page is being hosted by a fileserver (SMB/Windows). The clients are running IE6, 7, 8 or 9. The OS is mostly Windows XP but we're upgrading them to Windows 7 (with IE 8)

Comment: well you can check IE6 and IE7 support to html5 by visiting here... http://html5test.com/compare/browser/ie06.html . it is mostly nt supported in the older browsers.\

Answer (score 1):

If you're just submitting a form and need to get its values on the next page (the page in the form's `action` attribute), you can submit the data using `GET` and read it from the URL on the next page.

When you submit the form, the URL will be something like

```
http://mysite.com/submit.html?input1=foo&input2=bar
```

You can read the parameters using [the following](http://www.netlobo.com/url_query_string_javascript.html) JS function.

```
function gup( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return results[1];
}
```

Now if this is *not* the case, and you need it to stay across multiple pages, I would go with `sessionStorage` or `localStorage` as NejiHyuga suggests.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript executes at Client side. So you could save Data in Cookies or something like this at Client side and send it to the server when necessary. Or you hide the information in form variables, i think you need a script on server side to handle the data.

Answer (score 0):

NeijiHyuga answered this but I do have a plugin I built for this purpose on GitHub if you want to check that out.

You can use session or local storage.

https://github.com/sebringj/jquery.dumbformstate

HTA, wow. That's an interesting employer you got there.

Comment: LoL! Yea he's a decade behind the current trend but thats what he wants.

Comment: you could look at jQuery Mobile as well and wrap it within the HTA, that way, you could actually learn something useful while wrapping it. Just don't lead on you are learning something new.